# Reload .bashrc during Vagrant Provisioning

Tags: bash, vagrant, rbenv

I am using shell provisining for Vagrant, and am trying to install rails with rbenv.

Following this guide:

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

I have arrived at this working script

```
# Update sources:
whoami
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev curl git-core sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev git libssl-dev


#install rbenv and Ruby 1.9.2
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ruby-build
~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh
~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.1.2
~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv global 2.1.2
```

The above guide uses `exec $SHELL` to add rbenv to the $PATH. I have that command, `bash`, `source .bashrc`, and more. Either they don't refresh the $PATH variable, or they exit the provisioning script early. So right now I have to call rbenv by its full path. Is there a way to reload bash, so I that I can refresh $PATH during a Vagrant provisioning script?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason to not just `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` in your script as-is? That will modify your environment for the current session. Alternatively, it *should* work to use `source ~/.bashrc` in your script after appending to the relevant file... If that doesn't work, then something weird is happening.

Note that bash does not just generally read the .bashrc file at startup. It does so in the specific case that it is started interactively and not as a login shell. Most programmatic invocations of bash will be non-interactive. You can specify a file for bash to read at non-interactive invocation by setting the `BASH_ENV` environment variable before invoking the shell.

Comment: I was using the same script, or one similar to provision a vagrant box and I was having the same problem. I used the suggestion in this answer and it worked like a charm. I also added the export to the bashrc, but just doing the export in the script directly worked like a charm. Thanks CBHacking